# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [137, 68]

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, data-cleaning

I encountered an error while building a linear regression model. Judging by their shape, it seems appropriate.

```py
X = df_one_hot[features]
y = df_one_hot["price"]

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 42)
model = LinearRegression().fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
RMSE = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
print("RMSE: ", RMSE)
```

X.shape

```py
(205, 46)
```

y.shape

```py
(205,)
```

X_train.shape

```py
(137, 46)
```

y_train.shape

```py
(68, 46)
```

This is the error:

```py
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_7740\1016843113.py in <module>
      1 X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 42)
----> 2 model = LinearRegression().fit(X_train,y_train)
      3 y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
      4 RMSE = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
      5 print("RMSE: ", RMSE)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    660         accept_sparse = False if self.positive else ["csr", "csc", "coo"]
    661 
--> 662         X, y = self._validate_data(
    663             X, y, accept_sparse=accept_sparse, y_numeric=True, multi_output=True
    664         )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    579                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
    580             else:
--> 581                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    582             out = X, y
    583 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
    979     y = _check_y(y, multi_output=multi_output, y_numeric=y_numeric)
    980 
--> 981     check_consistent_length(X, y)
    982 
    983     return X, y

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    330     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    331     if len(uniques) > 1:
--> 332         raise ValueError(
    333             "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: %r"
    334             % [int(l) for l in lengths]

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [137, 68]
```

I can't build a linear regression model despite all I've tried

Comment: The order of the return values in your train_test_split call are not correct.

Comment: ahahah Thank you. I've been trying to fix the problem for hours. Thank you so much.